# UK visa blank refusal letter without reason for refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I received my refusal letter today for my standard visitor visa application for the UK. However, the reason for refusal is not mentioned anywhere on the letter and it appears more of an unfilled template. How may I proceed after this? Do I contact them and how do I do that? or should I just reapply?
I am currently living in Egypt.

Please check the attached letter.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59364/discussion-on-question-by-dooha333-uk-visa-blank-refusal-letter-without-reason-f).

Answer (score 67):

I would try to get in touch with the consulate to explain that the refusal notice

- does not in fact give the reason for the refusal,
- does not identify the entry clearance officer, and
- appears to be an "unfilled template," as you note.

Presumably, after you explain this, they will make arrangements to give you a proper refusal notice.

The British embassy in Cairo has a consular section, and there is a consulate general in Alexandria.  Contact information for both may be found at https://www.gov.uk/government/world/egypt.

To elaborate on the insufficiencies of your refusal notice, you can refer to the [Immigration (Notices) Regulation 2003](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2003/658/introduction/made).  This has been [amended](http://www.refworld.org/docid/47fdfaf313.html) a few times, but I did not find a consolidated version.  In particular, the notice fails to meet these requirements, at least:

- 5(1)(a) [A notice given under regulation 4(1) is to include or be accompanied by a statement of the reasons for the decision to which it relates.]
- 5(3) [the notice ... shall also include, or be accompanied by, a statement which advises the person of (a) his right of appeal and the statutory provision on which his right of appeal is based; (b) whether or not such an appeal may be brought while in the United Kingdom; (c) the grounds on which such an appeal may be brought; and (d) the facilities available for advice and assistance in connection with such an appeal.]
  -

Comment: In the refusal notice the ECO says an interview has not been necessary. Then he says he has taken into account the interview with the applicant. It appears that these "irregular" refusals have become common. I suppose that is expected when the whole process lacks transparency with no option of an appeal.

Comment: @greatone That would seem to be just another aspect of the "unfilled template" (as mentioned above). One of those phrases would be _deleted_ in a correctly completed document.

Comment: Would an appeal have a chance? Looking at this sad excuse for an official document, it clearly states no reason why the application is refused, it makes it quite clear that the examiner just dreamed that he interviewed the applicant, so I think that the application should be accepted. In other words, I see nothing wrong here except that the application should have been accepted, since there are no reasons to reject it.

Comment: @gnasher729 appeals are generally only allowed for rights violations, so the appeal would probably not have a chance, but a reapplication might, depending on the reasons for the new refusal.

Comment: @phoog isn't failure to provide the legally required explanation for visa denial a rights violation?

Comment: @RobertColumbia I doubt it, but I do not know.  I suppose, even if it is, that the violation could be remedied by supplying the proper refusal notice (if one exists) or by reconsidering the application afresh without charge, if the reasons for the refusal were never in fact documented.