# Visitor visa refusal on deception

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

UK visa refusal on deception, the pages are shown below:

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: If anyone can help me find the solution.

Comment: They haven't specified any topic on which they have issued deception

Comment: Is it actually blank in the section where it says "I have refused your application ... because:" ? (Also,what is your question?)

Comment: Did you give some wrong document or wrong reason? Which kind of visa did you applied?

Comment: @Giacomo  I think it is not about the reasons for visiting, the problem is with his documents.

Comment: @ChowLu I'm not sure. It is possible that he applied as refugee or other humanitarian visa (see "mandatory suitability ground" on the letter). It seems that these reasons were non plausible (he is not in danger)

Comment: @Giacomo Yes you are righgt there too, anything is possible but he he is not giving us more info on the issue.

Comment: @jignesh Can you give a brief summery of where you applied, which nationality/passport are you using?

Comment: Jignesh - did you submit your documents to VFS yourself?

Comment: Did you use any agencies or did you submit the application yourself? This could be a fake from a dishonest agency that just takes your money.

Comment: No I haven't given any wrong documents

Comment: Hi, I have applied for visitors visa for my parents.

Comment: They have applied by parson but used agent

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You know who signed this refusal letter? His/Her name was

> **Enter ECO Name**

**This is a clerical error**. Contact them and ask for a proper refusal letter. Don't worry and don't pay attention to people telling you you are banned or you have serious problems with your documentation. You may or may not but this refusal letter as it is is **invalid**.

Read this  (comes from your refusal letter)

> I have refused your application for a visit visa because i am satisfied that **enter the reasons why the relevant paragraph of Part V3 Applies**.

Then, it also says

> - an interview with you
> - an interview with your sponsor

But for a standard visitor visa neither of those are conducted.

Comment: We pay good money for the services of the Entry Clearance Officers. Mistakes like this are simply unacceptable.

Comment: I never suggested accepting this mistake. From a history of TSE questions we know that they will respond to this mistake and rectify it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because **reason(s) this answer is useful and of high quality**.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a proper refusal notice at all. It's a blank template that the Entry Clearance Officer is supposed to fill in with the reasons for their decision. You can see text like "enter ECO name" and "see suggested refusal wordings" that is meant for the officer and is supposed to deleted and replaced with the appropriate reasons before it is given to you. One of the template sections concerns deception; they're only supposed to include it if it's warranted; so there's no reason to conclude based on this that you were refused for deception. In short, someone goofed here.

We've seen this happen before. See [UK visa blank refusal letter without reason for refusal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/uk-visa-blank-refusal-letter-without-reason-for-refusal). You should contact the consulate or the VFS that gave you this letter and tell them there's been a mistake. The regulations state that you're supposed to receive a proper notice, and this isn't one.

Once you have an actual refusal notice with the real reasons (which very well may not be for deception at all), come back and post it here, and people can help you figure out what happened.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because **reason(s) this answer is useful and of high quality**.

Comment: I have applied for visitors visa for my parents