# Unclassified UK Visa refusal

Tags: uk

I applied Short term tourism UK visa. 
After week I submitted all my documents I received my documents back in mail. They refused my visa , they did not give explanation why they refused it. There is only words as reason says UNCLASSIFIED. What does it mean ? Can someone tell me ? [image]

Comment: Interesting, can we see the refusal letter with your personal information removed?

Comment: At the next page it only says UNCLASSIFIED

Comment: That looks like a technical error, it may or may not be a refusal we can't tell yet. But you will have to contact them via their helpline to explain the situation and may end up having to re-apply.

Comment: How I can contact with them ? We don’t have their visa councilar department in my country.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk

Comment: It looks like there is text on the back of that page?  Anything relevant?

Comment: If this is completely blank with the only thing being UNCLASSIFIED then it means the incompetence and lack of quality assurance at the visa office has reared its head again. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/93879/uk-visa-blank-refusal-letter-without-reason-for-refusal

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.